# How to define a route with node js?

Tags: node.js

Good morning everyone!
Since yesterday, I try to define a route for a simple nodejs api. In my case the server calls the express module, it also calls the file 'messCtlr.JS' and defines the route.

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var messCtlr = require("./routes/messCtlr");

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/cooldb', {useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false}, function(err){
  if(err){throw err}
});
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/messages', messCtlr);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.json({
    message: 'Behold The MEVN Stack!'
});
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`listening on ${port}`);
});
```

In the messCtlr.js file, the Router of the express module is called and enclosed in the router variable which is exported at the end of the script.

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Mess = require('../models/Message')

router.get('/messages', (req,res)=>{
    res.json({
        blabla: 'le message est ici'
    })
});
module.exports = router;
```

When I launch the server (port: 4000) and I type 'localhost: 4000 / messages', I get a error 'cannot get / messages'. Where did i make the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Have you kept the below snippet in your `routes/index.js` file?

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/messages');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in the messCtlr.js, If you pass the /messages in messCtlr.js then you need to call URL like http://localhost:4000/messages/messages or if you want to call URL like http://localhost:4000/messages then you need to just update your messCtlr.js as given below example.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Mess = require('../models/Message')

router.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.json({
        blabla: 'le message est ici'
    })
});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `messCtlr.js` line 7 needs to changed, and the final output will look like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Mess = require('../models/Message')

router.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.json({
        blabla: 'le message est ici'
    })
});
module.exports = router;
```